# How can I override "Stop mode" printer state on Brother HL-1110?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printer, brother-printer, toner

My LED is blinking in way matching documentation at https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=nz&lang=en&prod=hl1110_us_eu_as&faqid=faq00000065_063

Note that it is NOT about case where both green and orange light is present ("Ready and Error LEDs are lit").

I already used continue mode to override printer demands to throw away working toner.

Now only error led (orange) is blinking, green one is not lit.

Now it again demands to throw away working toner. How can I override its nonsense demands? Is it saving usage count on the toner cartridge? Or can I confuse it by swapping new one and then again using "depleted" one?

I am using Linux, Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (or Lubuntu to be more specific)

[https://support.brother.ca/app/answers/detail/a_id/103191/~/how-do-i-clear-the-message-toner-ended%3F](https://support.brother.ca/app/answers/detail/a_id/103191/%7E/how-do-i-clear-the-message-toner-ended%3F) was useless, as it tells me to throw away working toner (strictly speaking, not working right now - but only due to some weird DRM-like evil thing)

Comment: To downvoter: I would appreciate comment what went wrong here! Is question unclear? Asked at wrong place? Or just they had bad day? If I do not know what went wrong I cannot improve!

Comment: What model is your printer ? Try [this method](https://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2370dw_us&faqid=faq00002828_004) to always Continue. Another one is [here](https://cybertext.wordpress.com/2015/01/23/stop-brother-laser-printer-replace-toner-message/).

Comment: Brother HL-1110, as mentioned in title. As noted, "I already used continue mode to override printer demands to throw away working toner."

Comment: I know you did, but the question is if you did it using the above two methods that are supposed to stop the message for good.

Answer (score 0):

Googled this: `brother hl-1110 reset toner` to find the below methods. I do not have this printer so can't test this, proceed at your own risk.

### Method 1

[Service manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1272269/Brother-Hl-1110.html?page=89#manual) (pg4-7, PDF pg89) detailing how to do it:

6.RESETTING TONER MANUALLY

This function allows you to manually perform the same operation as when the toner cartridgeis replaced with a new one. This function provides a method to deactivate the following errors: when a new toner cartridge cannot be detected, and the toner life cannot be reset.

1. Check that the power switch is turned OFF. Press and hold the power button and check that the Ready and Error LEDs are lit. Then open the top cover and check that the Error LED goes out and only the Ready LED is lit.
2. Take out the drum unit and check that the Error LED is lit. Check that the Ready and Error LEDs are lit and release the power button. Check that all LEDs go out.
3. Set the drum unit and close the top cover.
4. Press the power button twice. Check that the Error LED is lit
5. Reset the counter by:

   a) Pressing the power button five times for the starter toner

   b) Pressing the power button six times for the standard toner

### Method 2

[Steps below were copied from cartridgeworld.co.uk](https://www.cartridgeworld.co.uk/brother-toner-and-drum-reset-methods/) :

1. Switch-off the printer
2. Press and hold the on/off button
3. When all the LEDs turn on, open the cover and remove the toner cartridge + drum unit
4. Release the on/off button
5. Re-install the toner cartridge + drum unit back into the printer and close the printer cover
6. Press on/off button twice and wait for 2 seconds
7. Press on/off button 6 times
8. Now printer is ready for printing

Comment: "check that the Ready and Error LEDs are lit" this is not applicable, only error LED is blinking. I will clarify question.

Comment: Maybe you need to hold power button longer on that step?

Comment: I already used continue mode to override earlier printer demands to throw away working toner. Your source explicitly mentions "check that the Ready and Error LEDs are lit". Brother documentations mentions "toner low" and "end of toner" as separate and provides info how first may be overridden.

Comment: Are you skimming? My steps mentions starting with printer off then you hold a button for a period of time indicated by the different lights. Toner low continue is pressing 7x times. Different things yes. I don't know how else to help me if you don't read & try the steps slowly

Comment: "When all the LEDs turn on" this step is applicable only when it is "toner low" state, not "end of toner". I already used continue mode

Comment: "Press and hold the power button and check that the Ready and Error LEDs are lit." - again, that is sign of "toner low" state. In "end of toner" state only orange one is lit, and green one is not lit.

Comment: Did you try the steps? That is a yes or no question. I agree those LED's mean that NORMALLY, but this is a different scenario, we are starting from an OFF state, holding power button until the lights do something to indicate its in that special mode to proceed. Lights can mean different things at different times. This is my last comment, either try the steps or don't